# To edit or delete an answer you wish to re-answer after a downvote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deletion

I am asking this as I recently answered a question badly, and on going back to redo it from scratch it had got a deserved downvote. I have two questions:

1) I first deleted my post as my new answer was not a refinement of the old answer but a new approach, but then undeleted and edited the initial starting from scratch. Would I have been best to delete then redo from scratch or to edit the original (from scratch), or indeed added another answer keeping the doofer (it's sometimes instructive to see why something isn't the 'right' answer)? Plus if I had deleted what happens to the downvote as it's still there on the edit?

2) How does the voting and editing system work. I mean lets say I vote someone's answer down and then they tidy it up to an answer I would have voted up, how do I know that's the case, do I have to check back manually?

Comment: 2) I'm afraid you do have to check back manually. We don't have a mechanism for alerting the downvoters, when a downvoted question/answer has been edited. I guess it's much the same way that we have no automatic way of notifying the users who voted to close a question about it getting edited.

Comment: 1) If your answer is a completely new approach, I think it would be ok to delete the failed attempt, and start with a fresh post. OTOH, if you just fix a problem in the first answer, then it feels more honest to edit that instead. In between? I don't know where to draw the line. A user who deletes a lot of answers will begin to attract negative attention, so exercise a bit of care, and don't overdo this.

Comment: There are probably some disadvantages to deleting the downvoted answer, rather than rehabilitating it.  See [Deleting a downvoted answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13026/deleting-a-downvoted-answer?rq=1) for why it is an allowed practice.  If your participation in answering is otherwise good, any disadvantage/penalty will be negligible and age away.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, thanks for the info. That's why I decided to undelete and take the pain as even though it was a new approach 'spiritually' it was an edit in my heart, and as you intimate we all got to look after our Kharma.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks. I've learnt a few things tonight, my comment was to both you and Jyrki but you can't add two people to a comment!